# Ubuntu 22.04.3 randomly crashes after failed update

Tags: updates, 22.04, crash

I turned on my laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and it started a update, (I was prompted about this while shutting down previously). The progress bar went upto 99% in about 2 mins then got stuck there for about 2hr, out of desperation, I force shutdown the laptop and turned it back on, updated all the packages(using apt), rebooted again and it seemed to be running fine, however it freezed and crashed after like half and hour. The screen freezed then some random text showed up and then the screen went blank(laptop still on), I had to force shutdown and restart again and it seemed to be fine again but same thing repeated after some time. It seems to be crashing after some random time since the failed update. Is there anyway to fix it?